# Thread Stopping and Method execution

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have a thread that waits for user input for 3 seconds, if the user clicks the button execute "done" and if he doesn`t click in 3 seconds execute "not". I searched through stackoverflow but couldn't find an exact and simplified answer. Sorry if this is a repeat and/or noob question.

Here is the code I have for the moment but feel free to offer me another way, couldn't solve it with this;

```
private Thread thread;
TextView maintext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MainActivity myActivity = this;

    maintext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);

}



public void start(View view){

    changeText("Waiting.");
    thread=  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(3000);

                }

            }

            catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();


}

public void done(){
    maintext.setText("You pressed the button in 3 seconds");
}

public void not(){
    maintext.setText("You failed");
}

public void changeText(String text){

    maintext.setText(text);

}

public void click(View view){

    synchronized(thread){
        thread.notifyAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. It is not clear what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `CountDownLatch`?

Construction (in your class instance variable declaration, i.e. the place where `thread` is declared now):

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

In your waiting thread (called `start`), instead of creating and starting that `Thread`:

```
// wait for it to be notched or for timeout
boolean buttonPressed = latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (buttonPressed) {
    ....
}
```

And in your button click listener (that is not shown in your post, usually it's configured like `clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {`):

```
latch.countDown();
```

**Later addition**

But please note that if that `start()` method is run in a UI thread, waiting on it will simply freeze the UI which is not what you want. Another approach would be to use something like events. Define two events: 'three seconds passed' and 'the button was pressed' and process them.

Instance variables:

```
private boolean buttonPressed = false;
private boolean expired = false;
private final Object monitor = new Object();
```

Timer initialization:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            if (!buttonPressed) {
                // change text to 'You failed'
                expired = true;
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}, 3000);
```

In your button click listener:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    if (!expired) {
        // change text to 'You pressed the button in 3 seconds'
        buttonPressed = true;
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

There is no need to block any thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer but I couldn't implement this as it is the first time Im trying to use a CountDownLatch. I read the javadoc of it but still don't understand how to use this in my code. Sorry about being so noob :)) Can you implement this in the code I pasted here so I see how to use it.

Comment: Elaborated a bit

Comment: Crashes the app :(( I think the solution is to use the thread as I am connecting all buttons to different methods. Thanks a lot for trying to help but this is not the way maybe.. :/

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer will help you

```
private boolean isActive; //globally declare

    changeText("Waiting.");
    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (!isActive) {
                isActive = true;
            }
        }
    };
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,3000);

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!isActive) {
        done();
    } else {
        not();
    }
}



public void done() {
    mainText.setText("You pressed the button in 3 seconds");
}

public void not() {
    mainText.setText("You failed");
}

public void changeText(String text) {
    mainText.setText(text);
}
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.